# Add item to tree control

Tags: c++, mfc, treecontrol

I have an object of the my own class and `CTreeCtrl`.
I have opportunity add items to `CTreeCtrl` like

```
hTree = treeObject->InsertItem(L"All object", TVI_ROOT);
```

This code add items with text. Have i opportunity to add items with consist pointer of my object?

Comment: _".... with consist pointer of my object?"_ Did you mean to set item data like [documented here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftcz4k70.aspx)?

Comment: Yes. Byt i don't see the way add pointer to my item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @πάντα ῥεῖ suggests, `SetItemData` is the way to go. The type of the parameter should be `DWORD_PTR` allowing both 64-bit and 32-bit code to use the data as a pointer. You will have to cast the pointer. Read up on the methods of `CTreeCtrl` for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean with `treeObject` as a pointer to `const` object, then only if `InsertItem` is a `const` function.

Comment: My object is not constant. I want when I add an item in the tree, they consist text and I had the opportunity to call object

Comment: Sorry, then I don't understand your question.  Please re-state it more clearly.

Comment: I apologize for the vagueness of the wording. I have trees and some object of my class. I made like add an element to the tree to consist text and the pointer of my object. I just want to later by clicking on the item to get some information contained in this object